# How do I wrap a function with an object in a class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, oop, object, javascript-objects

Let's say I have a class named `Human`.

```
function Human(name, gender, age, personality){
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
    this.personality = personality; 
}
```

and I have some functions for the class such as `greeting` and `introduce`. So I create them like this:

```
Human.prototype.introduce = function() {
    var _gender = {"M": "Boy", "F": "Girl"};
    switch(this.personality)
    {
    case "passionate":
        alert("Hi, how are you? My name is " + this.name + ". I'm " + this.age + " years old " + _gender[this.gender] + ". ");
        break;
    case "aggressive":
        alert("I'm " + this.name + ". What you want? ");
        break;
    }
}

Human.prototype.greeting = function() {
    alert("Hi!");
}
```

Since `introduce` and `greeting` can be grouped by the same category (let's name it `speak`), how can I simply wrap this two functions with an object? I've tried this:

```
Human.prototype.speak = {};
Human.prototype.speak.greeting = function(){
    alert("Hi!");
}
Human.prototype.speak.introduce = function(){
var _gender = {"M": "Boy", "F": "Girl"};
        switch(this.personality)
        {
        case "passionate":
            alert("Hi, how are you? My name is " + this.name + ". I'm " + this.age + " years old " + _gender[this.gender] + ". ");
            break;
        case "aggressive":
            alert("I'm " + this.name + ". What you want? ");
            break;
        }
}
```

Now the question is, when a function is wrapped by an object, `this` in the introduce function is no longer referring to the instance. So how can I work this out?

I would like to call the function as this:

```
var eminem = new Human("Marshall Mathers", "M", 45, "aggressive");
eminem.speak.introduce();
```

Comment: What's the end goal? How do you want to call the functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Make Speak to A Class

Make `Speak` to a class, because logical grouping of variables and functionality in OOP are classes.

### Speak

```
function Speak(human) {
    this.human = human
}

Speak.prototype.greeting = function () {
    // ...
}

Speak.prototype.introduce = function () {
    // ..
}
```

### Human

```
function Human(name, gender, age, personality, greetWord) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
    this.personality = personality;
    this.speak  = new Speak(this)
}
```

### Example

```js
function Human(name, gender, age, personality, greetWord) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
    this.personality = personality;
    this.greetWord = greetWord;
    this.speak  = new Speak(this)
}

function Speak(human) {
    this.human = human
}

Speak.prototype.greeting = function () {
    alert(this.human.greetWord + "!");
}

Speak.prototype.introduce = function () {
    var _gender = { "M": "Boy", "F": "Girl" };
    switch (this.human.personality) {
        case "passionate":
            alert("Hi, how are you? My name is " + this.human.name + ". I'm " + this.human.age + " years old " + _gender[this.human.gender] + ". ");
            break;
        case "aggressive":
            alert("I'm " + this.human.name + ". What you want? ");
            break;
    }
}

var peter = new Human('Peter', 'M', 35, 'aggressive', 'Hi')
peter.speak.greeting()
peter.speak.introduce()
```

---

An other way to solve the solution would be to use apply.

## [Apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

> The apply() method calls a function with a given this value, and arguments provided as an array (or an array-like object).

### Code

```
var peter = new Human('Peter', 'M', 35, 'aggressive')
console.log(peter.speak.introduce.apply(peter))
```

### Example

```js
function Human(name, gender, age, personality){
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
    this.personality = personality; 
}

Human.prototype.speak = {};
Human.prototype.speak.greeting = function(){
    alert("Hi!");
}
Human.prototype.speak.introduce = function(){
var _gender = {"M": "Boy", "F": "Girl"};
        switch(this.personality)
        {
        case "passionate":
            alert("Hi, how are you? My name is " + this.name + ". I'm " + this.age + " years old " + _gender[this.gender] + ". ");
            break;
        case "aggressive":
            alert("I'm " + this.name + ". What you want? ");
            break;
        }
}

var peter = new Human('Peter', 'M', 35, 'aggressive')
console.log(peter.speak.introduce.apply(peter))
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can call it just "peter.speak.introduce" ? Because calling the apply everytime would be kinda pain in the ***.

Comment: @JohnnyCheuk I add a more oop solution

Comment: What if I cannot actually access and modify the Human constructor?

Comment: @Roman ... very nice. The best approach (the class and aggregation based one) one could come up with, in order to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @Roman 'If you call `Human.prototype.speak = new Speak(this);` outside the constructor, this will referring to Window

Comment: @JohnnyCheuk yes you are right. I'm sorry.   
But you should modify it in the construcor because of  [object composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition)

Comment: @ Roman so that means if I cannot access the constructor, I cannot solve this ?

Comment: @JohnnyCheuk ... Since it looks like your are not allowed changing the implementation of `Human`, is there any chance of introducing a factory function instead? The factory then is responsible of creating both instances `Human` and it's corresponding `Speak` via constructor and of gluing the latter to the former.

Answer (score 3):

You can `bind` the context of `this` in the function in its constructor

```
function Human(name, gender, age, personality){
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
    this.personality = personality;
    this.speak.introduce = this.speak.introduce.bind(this);
}
```

This way, `this` in your `introduce` function will always be the current instance of `Human`

Comment: Is there any way that I can bind it outside of the class?

Comment: I suppose that you could call `bind` after instantiation, but in order to have the syntax you want in your post, you'll need the `this` context inside the constructor

Answer (score 1):

```
function Human(name, gender, age, personality){

    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
    this.personality = personality; 

    var self = this; //this is how

    this.speak = {

        introduce: function() {

            var _gender = {"M": "Boy", "F": "Girl"};
            switch(self.personality)
            {
            case "passionate":
                alert("Hi, how are you? My name is " + self.name + ". I'm " + self.age + " years old " + _gender[self.gender] + ". ");
                break;
            case "aggressive":
                alert("I'm " + self.name + ". What you want? ");
                break;
            }
        },

        greeting: function() {

            alert("Hi!");
        }
    };
}

var hulk = new Human("Hulk", "M", 33, "aggressive");
hulk.speak.introduce();
```

Comment: I like your idea but I don't lke the `self`. So your idea without `self` but with `bind` .. https://jsfiddle.net/kbwy8wuf/

Comment: This works, but if all functions are defined inside the constructor, it would be kinda messy.

Comment: @JohnnyCheuk why don't you use [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)?

Comment: @caramba ... what will it be good for? It does not provide any additional benefit in order to solve the OP's original problem.

Comment: @PeterSeliger from what I understand with a class you don't need to do `Human.prototype.speak...` stuff cause the methods defined in the class are prototype methods => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Prototype_methods or am I wrong?

Comment: @caramba ... your are perfectly right. It's just another syntax. The *"mechanics"* is the same. And thats's, why switching to classes, does not solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @PeterSeliger well I think it would. Cause then he can use the `constructor()` and bind `this` to the functions in the class. Did you see fiddle from my first comment here? So I think that fiddle translated in a class would solve the problems.

Comment: @caramba ... The perfect approach meanwhile has been provided by Roman.

Comment: @caramba ... and referring to the fiddle of yours and all other till now provided solutions ... all of them, make `speak` an own property of a `Human` instance. But Roman's approach does it most sophisticated for it just links to prototypal `Speak` delegation.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the accepted answer you could write a few lines of code to automatically rebind all your functions using Object.keys and forEach.

```
function Human(name, gender, age, personality){
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
    this.personality = personality; 

    Object.keys(this.speak).filter(function(key) {
        return typeof this.speak[key] === 'function';
    }, this).forEach(function(key) {
        this.speak[key] = this.speak[key].bind(this);
    }, this);
}
```

Also you could easily improve this code to not only iterate the functions of the 'speak' object.